# ASP.NET: produce an error message when a non-numeric value is entered in a textbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, webforms, textbox

If a user enters a non-numeric value into a TextBox and presses a Button, I want to show an error message on a Label.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you asking how to change the text of a label in a winform when you click a button?

Comment: @ilkdrl: is this for ASP.NET WebForms, Windows Forms, WPF, etc?

Comment: WinForms, WPF or ASP.NET? They all have a TextBox.

Comment: sorry about that.its webforms

Comment: @lasse, i wanna do that users can not enter string value in textbox

Comment: Then why do you have it, the textbox I mean...

Comment: if you are trying to do validation then the answer will be different than simple modifying a label on a button click. In the later case, the textbox is irellevant. Might want to clarify your question.

Comment: Based on the other question he posted, he might be trying to accept numbers in order to calculate weight. By "string" he might be referring to non-numeric text. New coders sometimes just don't know the terminology.

Comment: Do you want to reload the page or not? If the latter, then you would have to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you saying you want to allow numbers only?

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox1" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ErrorMessage="Digits only, please" ValidationExpression="^\d+$" />
```

If this will allow numbers only, but will also allow you to skip the box entirely. If you want to make it required, add this:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ErrorMessage="Required" />
```

**Update:** If you would like to accept decimal values like "3.5" in addition to just "3", modify the ValidationExpression in the RegularExpressionValidator I supplied above to read "^\d+(\.\d+)?$"

Answer (score 2):

If you're working with ASP.NET webforms, perhaps you have some markup like this:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox1" Text="Default Text!" />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Click Me" OnClick="ChangeIt" />
<br />
<br />
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="default!" />
```

Then your code-behind will need a method to handle the button's click event. This will cause a post-back.

```
protected void ChangeIt(Object sender,EventArgs e)
{
   // ensure that the value in the textbox is numbers only.
   // there are always questions here whether you care about 
   // decimals, negative numbers, etc. Implement  it as you see fit.
   string userEnteredText = TextBox1.Text.Trim();
   long resultantNumber;

   if (!long.TryParse(userEnteredText, out resultantNumber))
   {
      Label1.Text = string.Format( "It looks like this isn't a number: '{0}'",
                    userEnteredText);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to check whether the input is a number or a string (and display an error if the input is a string), you could do something like this using the int.TryParse function:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int readValue;
    if (!int.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, out readValue))
        Label1.Text = "Error";
}
```